# How does (function).prototype work exactly?

Tags: prototype, javascript

I was reading through [How to Make a Javascript Library](http://www.mikedoesweb.com/2012/creating-your-own-javascript-library/) and I came across a point where the author calls:

```
    function _() {
        //Some obects and variables and junk. . .
}

_.prototype = {
    //some code. . .
    myFunction: function() {
        //Bla bla bla. . .
    }
}
```

And I was wondering how this works, and what it does. I understand that it creates a command of `_.myFunction()` but I don't understand how. I was wondering if it is the only way, and if it requires some other globals included somewhere.

Thanks in Advance!

Edit: experimenting with how this works, I have discovered the following:

```
function _$() {
    //Bla bla bla. . . 
}
_$.prototype {
    myFunc: function(foo) {
        return foo;
    }
}
```

Then, when I call `_$.myFunc` I get: `Unkown Syntax error: myFunc is not a function`
Just as Felix King said, it's not available. Could anyone tell me why, and how to make the function I set of `myFunc` accessible with `_$.myFunc(null);`

Comment: Presumably there is a piece above that that goes something along the lines of `var _ = function(){` or `function _(){`?

Comment: @JesseKernaghan Yeah there is, I'll add that to the question.

Comment: You are mistaken. Assigning to `_.prototype.func` does not make the function available as `_.func`. And the tutorial you linked to doesn't claim that either. Nor does it set `_.prototype` inside the function itself.

Comment: @FelixKling Where did I say I assigned _.prototype.func? 
And also, thanks for pointing out that it isn't in the function, I'll update it now.

Comment: @wyatt the .prototype functionality is a core part of how javascript works. I know you came here looking for solutions, but there are countless in-depth articles that will help you that already exist ( like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work ). I suggest searching and reading more resources before posting.

Comment: *"Where did I say I assigned _.prototype.func?"*  `_.prototype = { myFunction: function() { }}` assigns a function to `_.prototype.myFunction`.

Comment: If you want to know how `Func.prototype` works, I recommend to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript .

Comment: @FelixKling I'll go check out that article, and thanks for the tip on `.prototype.myFunction`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the `_.prototype` property for the object `_` is being modified. You can read more about `prototype` modification/method addition [here](http://phrogz.net/JS/classes/ExtendingJavaScriptObjectsAndClasses.html#prototype).

> Adding properties or methods to the prototype property of an object
>   class makes those items immediately available to all objects of that
>   class, even if those objects were created before the prototype
>   property was modified.

Answer (score 1):

I have what I was trying to do figured out. Prototype is simply an object type inside an object, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work?rq=1).

The second part, and what I was trying to do was set something accessable by `_$.function(args)`
The way to do this, discovered through expierements is:

```
var _$ = function() {
    //args and variables etc. . .
};
_$.myFunc = function(args) {
    return args;
}
```

Then, `_$.myFunc(5)` returns: `5`

Answer (score 0):

Though, question has been answered a year ago, but I think it worth sharing so that it may help reader.

```
function _() {
        //Some obects and variables and junk. . .
        // missing like was 
        return this;

}

_.prototype = {
    //some code. . .
    myFunction: function() {
        //Bla bla bla. . .
    }
}
```

Only confusion in above code is '_' , since naming guideline of javascript says "any variable or function can start with _".If I we write this code as follows :

```
 function Blah() {
            //Some obects and variables and junk. . .
            return this;
    }

  Blah.prototype = {
        //some code. . .
        myFunction: function() {
            //Bla bla bla. . .
        }
    }
```

Now I think everybody can use or understand how to use it. like Joke().myFunction().

So I think the confusion was '_' here.